# nmap http-form-brute fails for admin form in django

Tags: python, django, nmap

Trying to use nmap on localhost to bruteforce admin name/pass in Django framework. I've created simple Django application with one admin, started it and now I try to bruteforce the password like this:

```
nmap -p 8000 --script http-form-brute --script-args userdb=test.txt,passdb=test.txt,path=/admin/,hostname=localhost -vv -d -sT 127.0.0.1
```

test.txt contains two lines with words one of which is correct.

nmap produces:

```
Scanned at 2014-10-23 11:42:12 ope for 0s
PORT     STATE SERVICE  REASON
8000/tcp open  http-alt syn-ack
Final times for host: srtt: 1000 rttvar: 5000  to: 100000

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
NSE: Starting runlevel 1 (of 1) scan.
Read from C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap: nmap-payloads nmap-services.
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 6.90 seconds
       Raw packets sent: 0 (0B) | Rcvd: 0 (0B)
```

Server log contains this on requests:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 12312)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 595, in process_request_thread

    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line
129, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/simple_server.py", line 116, in handle
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 447, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

The error 104 happens when the socket connection got disconnected by the server and then dead socket is being used by the client.

I think in your case this was happened because Django login is involved with http cookies for 'session-id' and 'csrf-token'. Those things are required for properly login. I don't know how nmap going to handle the http cookies. You could use `curl` which has options to add all `http` client specifications.